# Hibernate - unique key as foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

I have unique key defined for an column. How can I map that as foreign key in hibernate?

```
Table A
-------------------------------------
id (PK) | oneMoreId(Unique) | column1


Table B
----------------------------------------------------
id(PK) | refId (Foreign key to A.oneMoreId) | column2 |
```

How can I define one to many relation ship between Table A and B (A 1--->* B) in hibernate.

Comment: Answer is in your question itself (one-many or whatever), all you need to do is little bit google search

Comment: Creating foreign key relations is one of the basic functions of Hibernate; I suggest reading a Hibernate starting tutorial. Start here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-associations-unidirset. I'm out of close votes but this question *is* off-topic (minimal-understanding).

Comment: My question was more towards Unique Keys. As per my knowledge hibernate supports only Primary Key as Foreign key. I was wondering is there any way to use Unique key as foreign key. When I try to do that I get following Exception :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/
Link above explains how to define relationship between table.

Comment: See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-associations-unidirset (and the entire associated tutorial).

Comment: My question was more towards Unique Keys. As per my knowledge hibernate supports only Primary Key as Foreign key. I was wondering is there any way to use Unique key as foreign key.

Comment: I don't think you can use unique key as foreign key. Foreign keys are always a primary key in other table. May be you can check on Natural keys.

Comment: In a normalized database a key cannot be both primary and foreign (in a non normalized db this only happens in one-to-one-or-zero relationships). You can easily make a foreign key unique, simply use it in a collection mapping in Hibernate and add a unique mapping constraint to it, just like any other unique key.

Comment: @Gayathri a foreign key can most definitely be unique, although that sometimes indicates room for structural improvements and normalization.

Comment: @JasonC: Agree a foreign key can be unigue. But unigues key from table A to be used as foreign key in table B, is not right. Also, I agree on structural improvements and normalization.